# Minikube doesn't Like VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

(This question is moved from stackoverflow site)

I need to use Kubernetes, but can't start minikube due to a Virtualbox issue. I had an old version of Virtualbox installed a few years ago. After removing the old one, I can't install the latest version. The followings are the output with the installation.

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox
...
Setting up virtualbox (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
vboxweb.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl 
status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
...
```

And

```
$ journalctl -xe
-- Unit virtualbox.service has finished shutting down.
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
-- Subject: Unit virtualbox.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit virtualbox.service has begun starting up.
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem virtualbox[11665]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem virtualbox[11665]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem virtualbox[11665]:    ...fail!
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited 
status
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
-- Subject: Unit virtualbox.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit virtualbox.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 29 09:30:11 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 29 09:30:12 oem systemd[1]: Reloading.
Feb 29 09:30:12 oem systemd[1]: Started ACPI event daemon.
...
```

How to resolve this problem?

**Update:**

Here is Linux kernal information:

```
$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.4.0-173-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-037) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) ) #203-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 15 02:55:01 UTC 2020
```

I run the installment again with a different command

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-qt
```

virtualbox information found under the help menu:

```
VirtualBox Graphical User Interface Version 5.1.38_Ubuntu r122592
```

When I run

```
$ minikube start
Starting local Kubernetes v1.7.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0301 20:39:45.722088    5013 start.go:129] Error starting host: Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is "WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.\n\t Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate\n\t headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.\n\n\t You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\n5.1.38_Ubuntur122592". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org.

Retrying.
E0301 20:39:45.722833    5013 start.go:135] Error starting host:  Error creating host: Error executing step: Running precreate checks.
: We support Virtualbox starting with version 5. Your VirtualBox install is "WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.\n\t Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate\n\t headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.\n\n\t You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.\n5.1.38_Ubuntur122592". Please upgrade at https://www.virtualbox.org
E0301 20:39:45.903514    5013 util.go:147] Error uploading error message: Error sending error report to https://clouderrorreporting.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/k8s-minikube/events:report?key=AIzaSyACUwzG0dEPcl-eOgpDKnyKoUFgHdfoFuA, got response code 400
```

I don't know why minikube still complains a low virtualbox version while virtualbox is higher than a version minikube needs.

**Update 2:**

After removing the existing installment, I reinstall virtualbox.

```
$sudo apt install virtualbox-qt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  virtualbox virtualbox-dkms
Suggested packages:
  vde2 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 64 not upgraded.
Need to get 7,517 kB/24.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 105 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 virtualbox-qt amd64 5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3 [7,517 kB]
Fetched 7,517 kB in 1s (4,104 kB/s)        
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
(Reading database ... 428864 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-dkms_5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox_5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-qt_5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-qt (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.23) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22+linuxmint1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
Loading new virtualbox-5.1.38 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.4.0-173-generic
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Setting up virtualbox (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
vboxweb.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-03-02 10:31:21 PST; 4ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 7748 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 02 10:31:21 oem systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem virtualbox[7748]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem virtualbox[7748]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem virtualbox[7748]:    ...fail!
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
Setting up virtualbox-qt (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.23) ...
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.47ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
```

It says falling on starting "VirtualBox Linux kernel module." Based on its instruction, the followings are output of two commands.

```
$ virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-03-02 10:31:21 PST; 9min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Mar 02 10:31:21 oem systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem virtualbox[7748]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem virtualbox[7748]:  * No suitable module for running kernel found
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem virtualbox[7748]:    ...fail!
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Mar 02 10:31:21 oem systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Unit entered failed state.
```

and

```
$ journalctl -xe
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem wpa_supplicant[1344]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a reason=4 locally_generated=1
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <warn>  [1583174632.1745] sup-iface[0x1b12570,wlp3s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz, 92000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem kernel: cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem wpa_supplicant[1344]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174632.1799] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Mar 02 10:43:52 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174632.2822] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem ntpd[2046]: Deleting interface #12 wlp3s0, 192.168.0.109#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=429 secs
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem ntpd[2046]: Deleting interface #13 wlp3s0, fe80::cc4f:3a38:1316:87a0%3#123, interface stats: received=0, sent=0, dropped=0, active_time=429 secs
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem wpa_supplicant[1344]: wlp3s0: SME: Trying to authenticate with cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a (SSID='SHAW-9F8AF9' freq=2462 MHz)
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem kernel: wlp3s0: authenticate with cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem wpa_supplicant[1344]: wlp3s0: Trying to associate with cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a (SSID='SHAW-9F8AF9' freq=2462 MHz)
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174633.2539] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem kernel: wlp3s0: send auth to cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a (try 1/3)
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem kernel: wlp3s0: authenticated
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem kernel: wlp3s0: associate with cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a (try 1/3)
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem kernel: wlp3s0: RX AssocResp from cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=2)
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem kernel: wlp3s0: associated
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem wpa_supplicant[1344]: wlp3s0: Associated with cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174633.2611] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174633.2678] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174633.2764] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem wpa_supplicant[1344]: wlp3s0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a [PTK=CCMP GTK=TKIP]
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem wpa_supplicant[1344]: wlp3s0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to cc:65:ad:0a:fc:3a completed [id=0 id_str=]
Mar 02 10:43:53 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174633.3004] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Mar 02 10:43:55 oem ntpd[2046]: Listen normally on 14 wlp3s0 192.168.0.109:123
Mar 02 10:43:55 oem ntpd[2046]: Listen normally on 15 wlp3s0 [fe80::cc4f:3a38:1316:87a0%3]:123
Mar 02 10:43:55 oem ntpd[2046]: new interface(s) found: waking up resolver
Mar 02 10:44:43 oem dhclient[1368]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.5 on enp4s0 to 192.168.0.1 port 67 (xid=0x12b680b8)
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem dhclient[1368]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.5 from 192.168.0.1
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174684.1527]   address 192.168.0.5
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174684.1527]   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174684.1527]   gateway 192.168.0.1
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174684.1528]   server identifier 192.168.0.1
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174684.1528]   lease time 3600
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174684.1528]   nameserver '64.59.144.100'
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174684.1528]   nameserver '64.59.150.143'
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174684.1528]   domain name 'vc.shawcable.net'
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem NetworkManager[1103]: <info>  [1583174684.1528] dhcp4 (enp4s0): state changed bound -> bound
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem dbus[1033]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service'
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has begun starting up.
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem dbus[1033]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
-- Subject: Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit NetworkManager-dispatcher.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem nm-dispatcher[9208]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [enp4s0]: new request (1 scripts)
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem nm-dispatcher[9208]: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [enp4s0]: start running ordered scripts...
Mar 02 10:44:44 oem dhclient[1368]: bound to 192.168.0.5 -- renewal in 1695 seconds.
```

**Update 3**

```
oem@oem /lib/modules $ find . -iname \*vbox\*
./4.4.0-77-generic/updates/vboxguest.ko
./4.4.0-77-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko
./4.4.0-77-generic/updates/vboxvideo.ko
./4.4.0-77-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox
./4.4.0-77-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf
./4.4.0-77-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest
./4.4.0-77-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo
./4.4.0-53-generic/updates/vboxguest.ko
./4.4.0-53-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko
./4.4.0-53-generic/updates/vboxvideo.ko
./4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox
./4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf
./4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest
./4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo
./4.4.0-112-generic/updates/vboxguest.ko
./4.4.0-112-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko
./4.4.0-112-generic/updates/vboxvideo.ko
./4.4.0-112-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox
./4.4.0-112-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf
./4.4.0-112-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest
./4.4.0-112-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo
./4.4.0-93-generic/updates/vboxguest.ko
./4.4.0-93-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko
./4.4.0-93-generic/updates/vboxvideo.ko
./4.4.0-93-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox
./4.4.0-93-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf
./4.4.0-93-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest
./4.4.0-93-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo
./4.4.0-173-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox
./4.4.0-173-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf
./4.4.0-173-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf/vboxsf.ko
./4.4.0-173-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest
./4.4.0-173-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/vboxguest.ko
./4.4.0-173-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo
./4.4.0-173-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
./4.4.0-137-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox
./4.4.0-137-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf
./4.4.0-137-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf/vboxsf.ko
./4.4.0-137-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest
./4.4.0-137-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest/vboxguest.ko
./4.4.0-137-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo
./4.4.0-137-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
./4.4.0-83-generic/updates/vboxguest.ko
./4.4.0-83-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko
./4.4.0-83-generic/updates/vboxvideo.ko
./4.4.0-83-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox
./4.4.0-83-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf
./4.4.0-83-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest
./4.4.0-83-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo
```

and

```
oem@oem /lib/modules $ dpkg -S vboxvideo.ko
linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-173-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-173-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-93-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-93-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-112-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-112-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-137-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-137-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-77-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-77-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-83-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-83-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
```

Answer (score 0):

The last-but-one line of your own question contains this message

> ```
> WARNING: The character device /dev/vboxdrv does not exist.
> Please install the virtualbox-dkms package and the appropriate headers, most likely linux-headers-generic.
> You will not be able to start VMs until this problem is fixed.
> ```

It's possible the package was downloaded but failed to install, or perhaps the dependencies for `virualbox` are missing. The clue will be in the `...` where you installed `virtualbox`

Indeed, in your edited question you now include this message,

> ```
> Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
> kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
> ```

I do suggest you read the messages that your system produces. Fix that problem and you'll be able to build the module.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I reinstall vritualbox, but can't get through. I put those output messages in my post.

Comment: Answer updated for you

Comment: Thanks very much for your input. Due to lacking knowledge on the subject, I don't know what I need to do based on the information in the output.

Answer (score 0):

Did you reboot between installing virtualbox and trying to start the service?

Most kernel modules don't require a reboot - some do - you might want to check for anything named vbox in /lib/modules. On my local machine I find....

```
 symcbean@myhost /lib/modules $ find . -iname \*vbox\*
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/updates/vboxnetadp.ko
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/updates/vboxvideo.ko
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/updates/vboxdrv.ko
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/updates/vboxpci.ko
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/updates/vboxnetflt.ko
 ./4.4.0-98-generic/updates/vboxguest.ko
 ./4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox
 ./4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxsf
 ./4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo
 ./4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxguest
 ./4.4.0-53-generic/updates/vboxvideo.ko
 ./4.4.0-53-generic/updates/vboxsf.ko
 ./4.4.0-53-generic/updates/vboxguest.ko

 symcbean@myhost /lib/modules $ dpkg -S vboxvideo.ko
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-98-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic: /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/kernel/ubuntu/vbox/vboxvideo/vboxvideo.ko
```

Comment: The output of those two commands is posted. It shows far more set of modules in a comparison of yours. I don't know whether that is a problem or not.